# scipy.optimize.minimize, travelling salesman with integer programming

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize, traveling-salesman

```
import numpy as np;
import math;
import random;
from scipy.optimize import minimize;


def matrixmult (A, B):
    rows_A = len(A)
    cols_A = len(A[0])
    rows_B = len(B)
    cols_B = len(B[0])

    Z = [[0 for row in range(rows_B)] for col in range(cols_A)]

    for i in range(cols_A):
        for j in range(rows_A):
            #for k in range(cols_A):
                Z[i][j] += A[i][j] * B[i][j]


    return Z

def constraint1(x):
    A=x
    rows_X = cols_X = len(x)
    ad = np.ones((len(x),1))  #makes a 7x1 array of ones 
    ad1 = x.sum(axis=1) # makes 7x1 array, each element is sum of each rows
    ad2 = np.matrix(ad1) 

    for i in range(len(x)):
        ad[i] = ad[i] - ad2[i] # sum of each row in a binary matrix must be 1 to indicate there is only one entrance or exit for each node
    #for j in range(cols_X):
     #ad = ad - ad1[i]


    return ad

def constraint2(x):
    rows_X = cols_X = len(x)
    ad3 = np.ones((1,len(x)))
    ad4 = x.sum(axis=0)
    ad5 = np.matrix(ad4)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        ad3[i] = ad3[i] - ad5[i]
    #for j in range(cols_X):
     #ad = ad - ad1[i]

    return ad3

def total(C):

    C = np.array([[np.nan,3,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3],[3,np.nan,3,7,np.nan,np.nan,11],[5,3,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,7,3,np.nan,3,9,11],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,3,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,9,3,np.nan,3],[3,11,np.nan,11,np.nan,3,np.nan]])

    X = [[0 for row in range(len(C))] for col in range(len(C[0]))]

    for i in range(len(C[0])):
        for j in range(len(C)):
            if math.isnan(C[i][j]) == False :
                X[i][j] +=  random.randint(0,1)
            else :
                X[i][j]==np.nan



    CX = matrixmult (C, X)
    cx = np.array(CX)
    x = np.matrix(X)
    print(x.sum(axis=1))
    print(x.sum(axis=0))
    print(x)
    print(cx)
    tot = 0
    for i in range(len(cx[0])):
        for j in range(len(cx)):
            if math.isnan(cx[i][j]) == False :
                #print (i,j)
                tot += cx[i][j]


     #for i in range(len(cx[0])):
            #for j in range(len(cx)):
                #if math.isnan(cx[i][j]) == False :
                    #print (i,j)
    return tot


C = np.array([[np.nan,3,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3],[3,np.nan,3,7,np.nan,np.nan,11],[5,3,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,7,3,np.nan,3,9,11],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,3,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,9,3,np.nan,3],[3,11,np.nan,11,np.nan,3,np.nan]])


con1 = {'type' : 'eq', 'fun' : constraint1}
con2 = {'type' : 'eq', 'fun' : constraint2}

cons = [con1,con2]

path = minimize(total, 12,method='SLSQP', jac=None, bounds=None, tol=None, callback=None, constraints = cons)

print(path)
```

I need to implement traveling salesman problem with linear programming. My intention to use python optimization tools. Its my first program in python and optimization programs. 
Since there are two constraints forces traveling salesman to visit(enter and leave) every node once, I wanted to create binary selection 'x' matrix with the same dimensions of cost matrix. Since there is one entrance every column of the selection matrix will sum to 1 and the same for each exit.
I have problems with the usage of scipy.optimize.minimize method. I am not able to send selection matrix to the constraint functions. I will appreciate if anybody helps, thanks in advance..  (sub-tour elimination constraints are not implemented yet)

Comment: scipy.optimize.minimize doesn't provide algorithms suitable for integer programs, so you may need a more suitable tool for this (there are many other optimization libraries for Python).

Comment: yes. i realized this yesterday.. now i am trying to make it with cvxpy tool. do you have any comment on this? Actually i have a small work on this which i could not go deep yet. I will add in below..

Answer (score 1):

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np
import math;
import random;

n = 7
#X = Bool(n , n)
#Y = Bool(n , 1)
#C = np.random.randint(1,5,(n,n))
C = np.array([[np.nan,3,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3],[3,np.nan,3,7,np.nan,np.nan,11],[5,3,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,7,3,np.nan,3,9,11],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,3,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,9,3,np.nan,3],[3,11,np.nan,11,np.nan,3,np.nan]])


#X = [[0 for row in range(len(C))] for col in range(len(C[0]))]
X = np.zeros((n,n))


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if math.isnan(C[i][j]) == False :
            X[i][j] +=  random.randint(0,1)
        else :
            X[i][j]== np.nan

#x = np.array(X, dtype = np.float64)
P = C*X
nodes = []

tot = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if math.isnan(P[i][j]) == False :   
            tot += P[i][j]
            if(P[i][j] >0):
                print (i,j)
                nodes.append((i,j))
print(nodes)
print(len(nodes))


objective = Minimize(tot)
constraints = []
constraints.append( sum_entries( X, axis=0 ) == 1 )
constraints.append( sum_entries( X, axis=1 ) == 1 )
#constraints.append( sum_entries(Y) == C )

prob = Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=GLPK_MI)
print (prob.value)
print(tot)
print(C)
print(X)
print(P)
#print(objective)
```

Now i have an edited optimization code using cvxpy packet. But it could not minimize the objective. I could not find more examples on cvxpy MILP examples. If you have any suggestion this will be nice. thanks